# BNHtmlPdfKit Header and Footer in PDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, pdf-generation, addsubview

I downloaded a forked copy of BNHtmlPdfKit on [GitHub](https://github.com/ppeelen/BNHtmlPdfKit) which adds support for a header and footer on a PDF file. The problem is that it only shows a white space on the header and footer when I try to add a subview with a image into it with the following code:

```
- (void)drawHeaderForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex
                          inRect:(CGRect)headerRect
{
    if (self.headerView != nil) {
        [self.headerView setTintColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        UIImage *img = [self imageWithView:self.headerView];

       [img drawInRect:headerRect];

        UIImageView *headerImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,500,500)];
        headerImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
        [self.headerView addSubview:headerImage];

    }
}
```

See full code below...

```
//
//  BNHtmlPdfKit.m
//
//  Created by Brent Nycum.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Brent Nycum. All rights reserved.
//

#import "BNHtmlPdfKit.h"

#define PPI 72
#define BNSizeMakeWithPPI(width, height) CGSizeMake(width * PPI, height * PPI)


#pragma mark - BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer Interface

@interface BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer : UIPrintPageRenderer

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat topAndBottomMarginSize;
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGFloat leftAndRightMarginSize;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *headerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *footerView;

@end


#pragma mark - BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer Implementation

@implementation BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer

- (CGRect)paperRect {
    return UIGraphicsGetPDFContextBounds();
}

- (CGRect)printableRect {
    return CGRectInset([self paperRect], self.leftAndRightMarginSize, self.topAndBottomMarginSize);
}

- (void)drawHeaderForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex
                          inRect:(CGRect)headerRect
{
    if (self.headerView != nil) {
        [self.headerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        UIImage *img = [self imageWithView:self.headerView];

        UIImageView *headerImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,500,500)];
            headerImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
            [self.headerView addSubview:headerImage];

        [img drawInRect:headerRect];
    }
}

- (void)drawFooterForPageAtIndex:(NSInteger)pageIndex
                          inRect:(CGRect)footerRect
{
    if (self.footerView != nil) {
        [self.footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        UIImage *img = [self imageWithView:self.footerView];

        [img drawInRect:footerRect];
    }
}

- (UIImage *)imageWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}

@end


#pragma mark - BNHtmlPdfKit Extension

@interface BNHtmlPdfKit () <UIWebViewDelegate>

- (CGSize)_sizeFromPageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize;

- (void)_timeout;
- (void)_savePdf;

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *outputFile;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWebView *webView;

@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^dataCompletionBlock)(NSData *pdfData);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^fileCompletionBlock)(NSString *pdfFileName);
@property (nonatomic, copy) void (^failureBlock)(NSError * error);

@end

#pragma mark - BNHtmlPdfKit Implementation

@implementation BNHtmlPdfKit

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    return [BNHtmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url pageSize:[BNHtmlPdfKit defaultPageSize] isLandscape:NO success:completion failure:failure];

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    return [BNHtmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url pageSize:pageSize isLandscape:NO success:completion failure:failure];

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize isLandscape:(BOOL)landscape success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithPageSize:pageSize isLandscape:landscape];
    pdfKit.dataCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:nil];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize isLandscape:(BOOL)landscape topAndBottomMarginSize:(CGFloat)topAndBottom leftAndRightMarginSize:(CGFloat)leftAndRight success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithPageSize:pageSize isLandscape:landscape];
    pdfKit.topAndBottomMarginSize = topAndBottom;
    pdfKit.leftAndRightMarginSize = leftAndRight;
    pdfKit.dataCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:nil];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    return [BNHtmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename pageSize:[BNHtmlPdfKit defaultPageSize] isLandscape:NO success:completion failure:failure];

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    return [BNHtmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename pageSize:pageSize isLandscape:NO success:completion failure:failure];

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize isLandscape:(BOOL)landscape success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithPageSize:pageSize isLandscape:landscape];
    pdfKit.fileCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename pageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize isLandscape:(BOOL)landscape topAndBottomMarginSize:(CGFloat)topAndBottom leftAndRightMarginSize:(CGFloat)leftAndRight success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithPageSize:pageSize isLandscape:landscape];
    pdfKit.topAndBottomMarginSize = topAndBottom;
    pdfKit.leftAndRightMarginSize = leftAndRight;
    pdfKit.fileCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url customPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithCustomPageSize:pageSize];
    pdfKit.dataCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:nil];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url customPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize topAndBottomMarginSize:(CGFloat)topAndBottom leftAndRightMarginSize:(CGFloat)leftAndRight success:(void (^)(NSData *pdfData))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithCustomPageSize:pageSize];
    pdfKit.topAndBottomMarginSize = topAndBottom;
    pdfKit.leftAndRightMarginSize = leftAndRight;
    pdfKit.dataCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:nil];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename customPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithCustomPageSize:pageSize];
    pdfKit.fileCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename];
    return pdfKit;

}

+ (BNHtmlPdfKit *)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)filename customPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize topAndBottomMarginSize:(CGFloat)topAndBottom leftAndRightMarginSize:(CGFloat)leftAndRight success:(void (^)(NSString *filename))completion failure:(void (^)(NSError *error))failure {

    BNHtmlPdfKit *pdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] initWithCustomPageSize:pageSize];
    pdfKit.topAndBottomMarginSize = topAndBottom;
    pdfKit.leftAndRightMarginSize = leftAndRight;
    pdfKit.fileCompletionBlock = completion;
    pdfKit.failureBlock = failure;
    [pdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:filename];
    return pdfKit;

}

#pragma mark - Initializers

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.pageSize = [BNHtmlPdfKit defaultPageSize];
        self.landscape = NO;

        // Default 1/4" margins
        self.topAndBottomMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
        self.leftAndRightMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithPageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.pageSize = pageSize;
        self.landscape = NO;

        // Default 1/4" margins
        self.topAndBottomMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
        self.leftAndRightMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithPageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize isLandscape:(BOOL)landscape {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.pageSize = pageSize;
        self.landscape = landscape;

        // Default 1/4" margins
        self.topAndBottomMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
        self.leftAndRightMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithCustomPageSize:(CGSize)pageSize {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.pageSize = BNPageSizeCustom;
        self.customPageSize = pageSize;
        self.landscape = NO;

        // Default 1/4" margins
        self.topAndBottomMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
        self.leftAndRightMarginSize = 0.25f * 72.0f;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_timeout) object:nil];

    [self.webView setDelegate:nil];
    [self.webView stopLoading];
}

#pragma mark - Class Methods

+ (CGSize)sizeForPageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize {
    switch (pageSize) {
        case BNPageSizeLetter:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(8.5f, 11.0f);
        case BNPageSizeGovernmentLetter:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(8.0f, 10.5f);
        case BNPageSizeLegal:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(8.5f, 14.0f);
        case BNPageSizeJuniorLegal:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(8.5f, 5.0f);
        case BNPageSizeLedger:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(17.0f, 11.0f);
        case BNPageSizeTabloid:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(11.0f, 17.0f);
        case BNPageSizeA0:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(33.11f, 46.81f);
        case BNPageSizeA1:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(23.39f, 33.11f);
        case BNPageSizeA2:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(16.54f, 23.39f);
        case BNPageSizeA3:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(11.69f, 16.54f);
        case BNPageSizeA4:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(8.26666667, 11.6916667);
        case BNPageSizeA5:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(5.83f, 8.27f);
        case BNPageSizeA6:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(4.13f, 5.83f);
        case BNPageSizeA7:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(2.91f, 4.13f);
        case BNPageSizeA8:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(2.05f, 2.91f);
        case BNPageSizeA9:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.46f, 2.05f);
        case BNPageSizeA10:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.02f, 1.46f);
        case BNPageSizeB0:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(39.37f, 55.67f);
        case BNPageSizeB1:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(27.83f, 39.37f);
        case BNPageSizeB2:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(19.69f, 27.83f);
        case BNPageSizeB3:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(13.90f, 19.69f);
        case BNPageSizeB4:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(9.84f, 13.90f);
        case BNPageSizeB5:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(6.93f, 9.84f);
        case BNPageSizeB6:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(4.92f, 6.93f);
        case BNPageSizeB7:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(3.46f, 4.92f);
        case BNPageSizeB8:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(2.44f, 3.46f);
        case BNPageSizeB9:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.73f, 2.44f);
        case BNPageSizeB10:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.22f, 1.73f);
        case BNPageSizeC0:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(36.10f, 51.06f);
        case BNPageSizeC1:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(25.51f, 36.10f);
        case BNPageSizeC2:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(18.03f, 25.51f);
        case BNPageSizeC3:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(12.76f, 18.03f);
        case BNPageSizeC4:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(9.02f, 12.76f);
        case BNPageSizeC5:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(6.38f, 9.02f);
        case BNPageSizeC6:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(4.49f, 6.38f);
        case BNPageSizeC7:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(3.19f, 4.49f);
        case BNPageSizeC8:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(2.24f, 3.19f);
        case BNPageSizeC9:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.57f, 2.24f);
        case BNPageSizeC10:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.10f, 1.57f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB0:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(40.55f, 57.32f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB1:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(28.66f, 40.55f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB2:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(20.28f, 28.66f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB3:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(14.33f, 20.28f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB4:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(10.12f, 14.33f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB5:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(7.17f, 10.12f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB6:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(5.04f, 7.17f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB7:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(3.58f, 5.04f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB8:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(2.52f, 3.58f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB9:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.77f, 2.52f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB10:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(1.26f, 1.77f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB11:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(0.87f, 1.26f);
        case BNPageSizeJapaneseB12:
            return BNSizeMakeWithPPI(0.63f, 0.87f);
        case BNPageSizeCustom:
            return CGSizeZero;
    }
    return CGSizeZero;
}

#pragma mark - Methods

- (CGSize)actualPageSize {
    if (self.landscape) {
        CGSize pageSize = [self _sizeFromPageSize:self.pageSize];
        return CGSizeMake(pageSize.height, pageSize.width);
    }
    return [self _sizeFromPageSize:self.pageSize];
}

- (void)saveHtmlAsPdf:(NSString *)html {
    [self saveHtmlAsPdf:html toFile:nil];
}

- (void)saveHtmlAsPdf:(NSString *)html toFile:(NSString *)file {
    self.outputFile = file;

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    if (!self.baseUrl) {
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost"]];
    } else {
        [self.webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:self.baseUrl];
    }
}

- (void)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url {
    [self saveUrlAsPdf:url toFile:nil];
}

- (void)saveUrlAsPdf:(NSURL *)url toFile:(NSString *)file {
    self.outputFile = file;

    self.webView = [[UIWebView alloc] init];
    self.webView.delegate = self;

    if ([self.webView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:)]) {
        [self.webView setSuppressesIncrementalRendering:YES];
    }

    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
}

- (void)saveWebViewAsPdf:(UIWebView *)webView {
    [self saveWebViewAsPdf:webView toFile:nil];
}

- (void)saveWebViewAsPdf:(UIWebView *)webView toFile:(NSString *)file {
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_timeout) object:nil];

    self.outputFile = file;

    webView.delegate = self;

    self.webView = webView;
}

#pragma mark - UIWebViewDelegate

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    NSString *readyState = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.readyState"];
    BOOL complete = [readyState isEqualToString:@"complete"];

    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_timeout) object:nil];

    if (complete) {
        [self _savePdf];
    } else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(_timeout) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0f];
    }
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error {
    [[self class] cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(_timeout) object:nil];

    if (self.failureBlock) {
        self.failureBlock(error);
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(htmlPdfKit:didFailWithError:)]) {
        [self.delegate htmlPdfKit:self didFailWithError:error];
    }

    self.webView = nil;
}

#pragma mark - Private Methods

- (void)_timeout {
    [self _savePdf];
}

- (void)_savePdf {
    if (!self.webView) {
        return;
    }

    UIPrintFormatter *formatter = self.webView.viewPrintFormatter;

    BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer *renderer = [[BNHtmlPdfKitPageRenderer alloc] init];
    renderer.topAndBottomMarginSize = self.topAndBottomMarginSize;
    renderer.leftAndRightMarginSize = self.leftAndRightMarginSize;
    renderer.headerView = self.headerView;
    renderer.footerView = self.footerView;

    [renderer setHeaderHeight:50.0f];
    [renderer setFooterHeight:50.0f];

    [renderer addPrintFormatter:formatter startingAtPageAtIndex:0];

    NSMutableData *currentReportData = [NSMutableData data];

    CGSize pageSize = [self actualPageSize];
    CGRect pageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, pageSize.height);

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(currentReportData, pageRect, nil);

    [renderer prepareForDrawingPages:NSMakeRange(0, 1)];

    NSInteger pages = [renderer numberOfPages];

    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < pages; i++) {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
//        
//        if (self.headerView != nil)
//        {
//            [self.headerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, pageSize.width, 50)];
//            
//            [renderer setHeaderHeight:self.headerView.frame.size.height];
//            [self.headerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
//        }

        [renderer drawPageAtIndex:i inRect:renderer.paperRect];
//        
//        if (self.footerView != nil)
//        {
//            NSLog(@"Page H: %f", pageSize.height);
//            
//            [self.footerView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, pageSize.height-50, pageSize.width, 50)];
//            [self.footerView.layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, pageSize.height-50, pageSize.width, 50)];
//            
//            [renderer setFooterHeight:self.footerView.frame.size.height];
//            [self.footerView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
//        }
    }

    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    if (self.dataCompletionBlock) {
        self.dataCompletionBlock(currentReportData);
    }

    if (self.fileCompletionBlock) {
        self.fileCompletionBlock(self.outputFile);
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(htmlPdfKit:didSavePdfData:)]) {
        [self.delegate htmlPdfKit:self didSavePdfData:currentReportData];
    }

    if (self.outputFile) {
        [currentReportData writeToFile:self.outputFile atomically:YES];

        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(htmlPdfKit:didSavePdfFile:)]) {
            [self.delegate htmlPdfKit:self didSavePdfFile:self.outputFile];
        }
    }

    self.webView = nil;
}

- (CGSize)_sizeFromPageSize:(BNPageSize)pageSize {
    if (pageSize == BNPageSizeCustom) {
        return self.customPageSize;
    }

    return [BNHtmlPdfKit sizeForPageSize:pageSize];
}

+ (BNPageSize)defaultPageSize {
    NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    BOOL useMetric = [[locale objectForKey:NSLocaleUsesMetricSystem] boolValue];
    BNPageSize pageSize = (useMetric ? BNPageSizeA4 : BNPageSizeLetter);

    return pageSize;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) BNHtmlPdfKit *htmlPdfKit;
```

then

```
self.htmlPdfKit = [[BNHtmlPdfKit alloc] init];
self.htmlPdfKit.delegate = self;
UIImageView *headerImage =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,50,500,500)];
headerImage.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"header_logo.png"];
self.htmlPdfKit.headerView = headerImage;
self.htmlPdfKit.pageSize = BNPageSizeA4;
[htmlPdfKit saveUrlAsPdf:[NSURL URLWithString:@"......."] toFile:@"......."];
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please [edit] your answer to give an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272), because they don't teach the solution.